# Simple, short, logical algorithm (which direction to go?)

Tags: algorithm, logic, distance, direction

Suppose we have a numbered circle. We want to go from point A to point B but we don't know if we should go to the left or to the right. How would you, using numbers, calculate in which direction you should go?

**Example:**

*We are currently on 1. We want to go on 5. I can see vissualy that 5 is closer so we go to the right. Also note, that you are always facing inwards.*

[image: img]

Comment: Are the numbers always in order? What is your "range" of visibility?

Comment: Yes, the numbers are always in order and you "see" (know) all the numbers.

Comment: Perform modular (base n) subtraction and use a threshold on n/2 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure that every calculation you do is modulo 6 (or `n`). That means -2 modulo 6 = 4. Then you can calculate once a clockwise trip and one counter clockwise. The clockwise trip is B-A, counter clockwise A-B. Then compare those two results, the lower one wins.

Example:

A = 1, B = 5

clockwise move: B-A = 4
counter cw move: A-B = -4 = 2

Example 2:

A = 5, B = 1

clockwise move: B-A = 2
counter cw move: A-B = 4

Comment: Simple, quick, excelent! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
If B > A
  If B - A > max/2, head CCW, else CW
Else
  If A - B > max/2, head CW, else CCW
```

i.e. if not crossing the wrap-around point (from 6 to 1) is more than halfway around, cross the wrap-around point!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution with a truth table (just to check right). ABS is shor to for Absolute Value.

```
a,b | x1 = abs(b-a) < max/2 | x2 = b-a > 0 | x1 == x2 
2,3 | true                  | true         | true
1,6 | false                 | true         | false
6,1 | false                 | false        | true
5,4 | true                  | false        | false
```

turn clockwise = ( x1 = abs(b-a) < max/2 ) == ( x2 = b-a > 0)

Answer (score 1):

I have two recursive, simple scala solutions for you. The basic idea is, that the way should not exceed a half round, which happens to be 3 in our case, but can of course be parametrized:

```
def fromAtoBClockwise (a: Int, b: Int) : Boolean = { 
  if (a > b) ! fromAtoBClockwise (b, a)
  else b - a  <= 3 }
```

The distance should not exceed 3, but to avoid subtracting 1 - 5, we turn the parameters and invert the result, if a > b.

```
def fromAtoBClockwise (a: Int, b: Int) : Boolean = { 
  if (a > b) fromAtoBClockwise (a, b + 6)
  else b - a  <= 3 }
```

An alternative way is, to just add 6, the size of the circle, to b, if it is lower.

Both work, but sometimes differ in the result, if both ways are of equal length.

With parameter for the size, and an odd size, you get the same result for both:

```
def fromAtoBClockwise (a: Int, b: Int, size: Int) : Boolean = { 
  if (a > b) ! fromAtoBClockwise (b, a, size)
  else b - a  <= size/2 } 


def fromAtoBClockwise (a: Int, b: Int, size: Int) : Boolean = { 
  if (a > b) fromAtoBClockwise (a, b + size, size)
  else b - a  <= size/2 }
```

Test (output condensed):

```
(1 to 5).map (a => (1 to 5).map (b => { if (a != b) println (a + " " + b + " " + fromAtoBClockwise (a, b, 5))}))

1 2 true    1 3 true    1 4 false   1 5 false
2 1 false   2 3 true    2 4 true    2 5 false
3 1 false   3 2 false   3 4 true    3 5 true
4 1 true    4 2 false   4 3 false   4 5 true
5 1 true    5 2 true    5 3 false   5 4 false
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering `a` == the first point, and `b` == the second point

```
pointAtoPointB = 0

for a to b
  pointAtoPointB ++

pointBtoPointA = 0

for b to a
  pointBtoPointA ++

if pointBtoPointA > pointAtoPointB
  go a to b
else
  go b to a
```

Comment: This is a simple solution, OK for my project I guess. But when there are more numbers this isn't really efficient.

Answer (score -1):

```
clockWise = B - A <  A + MAX - B
```

with B > A, swap positions accordingly.

Comment: What's with the dot after B, what does it represent?

Comment: `X < X + Y` where `Y > 0` is always true

Comment: Sorry, I obviously meant `B-A < A + MAX - B`, the dot was by mistake was typing from phone.

Comment: I changed your post reflecting your suggestion, but I believe you should already have the privileges to do that yourself.

Comment: @Blaisorblade I guess you were just a second quicker

Comment: For a = 4 and Max = 5, I always get 'true'.

Comment: What is B in your case? Remember B > A has to be true for this to work.